# Magento how to update product price programmatically

Tags: php, magento

I am trying to update product price programmatically by using this code.

```
$id = 1;
$product = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load($id);
$product->setPrice($price);
$product->setUrlKey(false);
$product->save();
```

but on product list page its showing like this like I have some special price.

[image]

When I use `var_dump()` its showing me changed price in `price` but in `min,max,final` still have previous price not the changed one.

```
["price"]=>string(7) "18.0000"
["final_price"]=>string(7) "16.0000"
["minimal_price"]=>string(7) "16.0000"
["min_price"]=>string(7) "16.0000"
["max_price"]=>string(7) "16.0000"
```

I have also tried this code

```
$product = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load($id);
$product->setPrice($price);
$product->setFinalPrice($price);
$product->setMinimalPrice($price);
$product->setMinPrice($price);
$product->setMaxPrice($price);
$product->setUrlKey(false);
$product->save();
```

but still showing me same result not changing values in `final,min,max`

Comment: Have you reindex the catalog_product_price from admin area.?

Comment: no can i do it from frontend

Comment: You can do from admin area or SSH commands.

Comment: $process = Mage::getModel('index/indexer')->getProcessByCode('catalog_product_price');
                    $process->reindexAll();
have tried this but still not working

Answer (score 1):

I'm doing this exact thing with my setup, and I was receiving your same exact problem.

Here's what I've got:

```
$product->setMinimalPrice($price)
    ->setPrice($price)
    ->setFinalPrice($price)
    ->save();
```

Also, I don't see any reason to use `$product->setUrlKey(false)` every time.

Comment: did u find any solution ?

Comment: @OBAID This is the solution that's worked for me. Although, if you're making this change on frontend code it's a little different. You're on Magento 1 right?

Comment: I am on magento 1 enterprise

Comment: Actually issue is price need to be re-indexing but when i am doing by this code $process = Mage::getModel('index/indexer')->getProcessByCode('catalog_p‌​roduct_price'); $process->reindexAll(); have tried this but still not working

Comment: its not working but when i am re-indexing from shell its working fine

Comment: @OBAID when you load the page and it shows it crossed out, does it change after refreshing another time?

Comment: @OBAID where are you changing the price at?

Comment: I am changing from frontend